# Should I have same version number for app and today extension widget

Tags: ios, today-extension

When I try to upload my app with Today Extension Widget to the App Store I get a warning about CFBundleShortVersionString Mismatch that says that app's and widget's versions are not the same.

Should they be always the same? Do I have to manually update version numbers in every extension in my app to be the same?

Comment: App Extensions and their containing apps must use the same build number (CFBundleVersion) and version number (CFBundleShortVersionString) as used in the other targets in the Xcode project.  https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2420/_index.html

Comment: And should it be updated manually?

Comment: Withing the same link you can find a section "Automatic Management "https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1827/_index.html

Comment: Hi @moonvader, Did u able to solve ur issue?

Answer (score -2):

No, it is not needed. It's just a warning. The app will not be rejected because the app version and widget short version mismatch.

Comment: That is not true, my app rejected because the extension didn’t have the same version.